# Sticky footer not working, despite all the settings are made

Tags: css

This is the page, [the page sticky footer isn't working](http://www.tracewhocalled.com/about.php) I want my sticky footer to work, all the codes are added correctly, despite that it isn't working. Can you please take a look and let me know what should I add or remove? Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to be more.. specific. Code, what have you tried? What does 'added correctly' mean? Whats correct? Where did you find this? We're not your personal debug team. (and one immediate thing: its `clear: both;`, not `all` - but that won't fix your issue)

Comment: @somethinghere Yes I need to add code and Css, I am very sorry for not adding that, You Sir, don't want to be my debugger. I will update the code later as its very late here. I may delete this thread, as it got a lot of down votes and start a new one with enough information, forgive me in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/ technique? If so - you need to add

```
height: 100%;
```

to your html element also

Comment: I added that already. That's what I mean by all the codes are added correctly. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Oh, okay- it;s not showing as a property on the linked example you gave in your question.

Comment: Can you tell me on what element the property is not being shown? Thanks.

Comment: your actual html element your css file should have 
html {height:100%;}
 - similar to the example file on the example I think you're working from
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much, it fixed the problem, the footers are now correctly in place where it should be. Thanks again Annie. Marked your answer as the correct answer i am looking for, Have a blast this weekend, Take care :)